# scala nested for-loop not working properly

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

got a weird scala for-loop issue. My goal is to output a list of feed-day, like 'A-20170531'. The code is pretty straightforward, but when I run it in Intellij, the second output is missing feed, it will be like '--20170531' . Then I copy the code to scala shell, it is working as expected.

Any ideas ?

```
  var feeds =
    """
      |A
      |B
      |C      
    """.stripMargin

  var days =
    """
      |20170531
      |20170601
    """.stripMargin
  var dayArr = days.split("\n").filter(_.trim.length != 0)
  var feedArr = feeds.split("\n").filter(_.trim.length != 0)
  System.out.println("feed size:"+feedArr.length  )

  for{
    feed <- feedArr
  } {
    System.out.println(feed)
  }

  for{
    feed <- feedArr
    day1 <- dayArr
  } {
    System.out.println(feed+"--"+day1)
  }
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce.
Scala 2.12.3, IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.3 (Build #IU-172.3968.16, built on August 22, 2017).
Output:

```
feed size:3
A
B
C
A--20170531
A--20170601
B--20170531
B--20170601
C--20170531
C--20170601
```

What's your Scala and IntelliJ?

---

Still can't reproduce with Scala 2.10.6 and each of

- IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.4 (Build #IU-145.2070, built on August 2, 2016)
- IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3 (Build #IU-145.1617, built on June 3, 2016)

I don't have 2016.1.2.

Looks like some weird bug. Try to update your IntelliJ.

Comment: scala is 2.10. IDE is IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2
Build #IU-145.971, built on April 29, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_77-b03 x86
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM by Oracle Corporation

Comment: @user1615666 Did you try to update your IntelliJ? Did it help?